# Photoshop: How to draw a guide with an exact distance from another guide

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Before drawing, I want to draw all guides for my layout. For example, I have a guide line named A already. After that, I want to have another guide named B  parallel with guide A and at 50px distance from it.

I have three solutions:

1. Draw line B and by "some way", I can see the current distance directly when I'm drawing, so I can make the distance exactly what I want it to be.
2. Draw line B. And then I use the `Ruler` tool to see the distance between the two guides. This method has disadvantages: maybe the ruler line that I draw isn't perpendicular with the guides and I'm not sure when the distance is enough.
3. There are other clever ways, that help me get this job done fast and easily, but that I don't know yet. I think Photoshop should support this feature.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What version of Photoshop are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Photoshop CC has a new feature called "[New Guide Layout](http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2014/10/new-guide-layout-and-new-guide-from-shape-in-photoshop-cc.html)" that is probably what you're after. `View > New Guide Layout`:

[image]

The alternative, and what I still am likely to do is setup a guide. Then use the `rectangular marquee` to determine size. Say you want 150px, I changed Marquee to Fixed Size and width 150px (can see this on top bar):

[image]

Snap left side to guide. Then add next guide:

[image]

Use arrow tool to easily move the marquee to next guide:

[image]

and repeat:

[image]

This is also useful if you don't have set measurements but want to make things even. Marquee from the edge of the document to a particular point then move the marquee to the opposite edge to set up both sides.

Comment: ah. very very nice :D I have read some simple posts that recommend using `rectangular marquee` tool but not tell exactly how. Your post teaches me well :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Deduce the location of your current guide, prefeably using the rulers ( <kbd>View > Rulers</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl / Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or the `Info` panel (<kbd>Window > Info</kbd>  or <kbd>F8</kbd>).
2. Choose <kbd>View > New Guide...</kbd> and key in a value 50 px higher than the amount you deduced.

Answer (score 1):

I use the [GuideGuide](http://guideguide.me/) plugin for drawing my guides. You can specify the number of columns, and gaps, both horizontal and vertical that you wish to create, and at the press of a button, it builds out your grid for you. I use it in CS6, so I cannot say for certain that it works in CC, but if CC allows 3rd party plugins, you should be able to use it.